# Transitioning height of a flex container

Tags: javascript, sass, flexbox, css-transitions

How could I transition the height of a flex container when the content is being displayed based on a button trigger inside that container?

I know I could change the code to specific height values and I could transition in that way, but I would like to keep it as a flex container.

Sorry if I was not that explicit. Also, an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/bigMV/pen/rNyvPbm

HTML:

```
     <div class="biography" >
  <div class="bioinfo">
    <h2>Jack Sparrow</h2>
    <h4 id="biotitle" >BIOGRAPHY</h4>
    <p class="bio">Hello! </br> My name is Jack Sparrow. </br>I am a qualified Personal Trainer based in Tortuga.
      </br>My journey to becoming a personal trainer stems from my early years in ski racing. I competed professionally in ski racing
      for over 8 years achieving huge success all over the Caraibbean and abroad.</p>
    <p class="bio" id="reveal">Exercise was a huge part of my skiing regime and working hard on improving my fitness enabled me to create more opportunities to succeed on the slopes. So, naturally, years down the line this has led me to become a qualified Personal Trainer with the notion of helping others realise their potential through consistent exercise. I currently operate a mobile Personal Training service within 10-15 miles from my address in Port Royal.</p>
    <button onclick="revealMe()" class="readmore" id="readmore">Read More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Scss:

```
 $color: #390e44;


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 500px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
  background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 2vw, 1.25rem);
}

:root {
  font-size: 16px;
}


.biography {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;

  margin: 0 5rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  margin: 5rem 0;
  text-align: left;
  transition: display 200ms linear 1s;



  .bioinfo {
    line-height: 1.75rem;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadeIn linear 1s ;

    .bio {


      animation: fadeIn linear 1s ;
    }

    #biotitle {
      font-family: "Roboto Mono";
    }

    #reveal {

      display: none;
    }

    .readmore {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      background-color: $color;
      padding: 1rem;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {

    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }

  100% {

    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

JS :

```
    function revealMe() {
let reveal = document.getElementById("reveal");
let readMore = document.getElementById("readmore")

  if (reveal.style.display === "none") {
    reveal.style.display = "block";
    readMore.innerHTML = "Read Less";
  } else {
    reveal.style.display = "none";
    readMore.innerHTML = "Read More";
  }
};
```

Comment: One way would be to ditch the `display: none / display: block` thing and transition a `max-height: 0; / max-height: 1000px`. *1000px* has to be a big enough value that you should never reach.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css